# ViewPager2 method onPageSelected(int position) returns incorrect position

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

This problem occurs when I start sliding to **Page1**, release the touch during page transition and slide to **Page0** again before the transition.
Method `onPageSelected(int position)` returns the position 1 even though **Page0** (in position 0) is shown.
Method `getCurrentItem()` returns the same value like `onPageSelected`.
I appreciate any idea how to solve this issue!

Comment: add some of your code

Comment: There's no need, I just updated the dependency to the latest version and now everything works fine. I don't know how I overlooked this, but I suppose it happens to everyone... 
Thanks for your concern!